# angular-translate directive as attribute vs element

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

When using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/), these do not produce the same behavior.

**Element**

```
<h3><translate>some.string.{{withinterpolation}}.in.the.middle</translate></h3>
```

**Attribute**

```
<h3 translate="some.string.{{withinterpolation}}.in.the.middle"></h3>
```

Am I doing something wrong? The [documentation](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive) says these should behave the same.

Comment: Where does it say in the docs that you can use it as an element? Every example I can see uses it as an attribute.
There's no reason to expect them to behave the same.

Comment: @HankScorpio it says it in the official documantation: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate

Comment: Could you be more explicit, and post a complete minimal example, along with the bahavior that you're observing for each case?